# "enriched in" vs "enriched with"

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, adjectives

I have a mixture of different things and now I artificially make it so that there is more of one component or ingredient in my product. Do I then say, "A is enriched in B" or "A is enriched with B"? Is there a difference in the meaning? Which one is more appropriate?

Example:

- enriched with vitamins
- enriched in a certain isotope
- a selection is made to be enriched in a certain type of contribution

("enriched with" yields twice as many Google results as "enriched in" but I think I would always tend to use the latter.)

Answer (score 3):

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enrich) includes the following different subsenses for **enrich**:

> enrich [verb]
>
> ...
>
> **1.1** Add to the nutritive value of (food) by adding vitamins or nutrients.
>
> *porridge oats enriched with extra oat bran*
>
> [M-W has *The drink is enriched with vitamin C.*]
>
> **1.2** usually as adjective enriched Increase the proportion of a particular isotope in (an element), especially that of the fissile
> isotope U-235 in uranium, so as to make it more powerful or explosive.
>
> *enriched uranium*
>
> [M-W has the more general *enrich ... to add or increase the
> proportion of a desirable ingredient*]
> ...
>
> *Uranium for the first atomic bomb and for nuclear reactors was enriched in the 235 isotope, as compared to the more abundant 238
> isotope, by gaseous diffusion.*

So 'enriched with X' means X has been added, often where there was none originally;

'enriched in X' means the proportion of X [already] in the sample etc has been increased.